# How to run Nuget's "reinstall" command on PowerShell or CMD

Tags: c#, package, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-update

I want to package my base assemblies. However I have to reinstall this packages on project when assembly update. Because I don't change version of assembly.

For this I try adding

`Update-Package -reinstall`

to pre-build event.

But I took "

> The command Update-Package -Reinstall" exited with code 9009.

error.

And I try run

`nuget Update-Package -Reinstall`

on PowerShell.

This time I took

> Unknown command: 'Update-Package'

error.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there nobody that help me?